# How can I use multiple keywords with REGEXP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have a query like so

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE interests REGEXP :interests
```

since interests are varied, I have an array of submitted interests that I'm imploding to reach the database like `golf|soccer|tennis`. I'm then using that array to replace :interests but MYSQL is throwing an error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: property queryString is read only

Idealy the query should read:

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE interests REGEXP golf|tennis|chess
```

I'm using PDO, what's the workaround I can use?

EDIT: This is the other php code, as requested

```
$keys = implode('|', array_filter($f3->get('keywords')));

//query the database, looking for matches in the users table.
$q = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE interests REGEXP :keywords");
$q->execute(array(':keywords' => $keys));
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$q->fetchAll();
```

Comment: That error `property queryString is read only` looks like a PDO error from PHP code, not a SQL error.   Show some associated PHP code.

Comment: If you bind the string `"golf|soccer|tennis"` in place of `:interests` it ought to work exactly as you intended, so your error is likely in the implementation, not the idea.

Comment: Your PHP code all looks correct, but can you also show `var_dump($keys)` so we can see what that array actually looks like? As you have it, I would expect everything to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $q->fetchAll();
```

I retraced my steps and assigned the result to a variable and everything worked!